# axios - execute a call before retrying a request

Tags: reactjs, axios

I would like to make an axios call if the previous call returned a specific return code before retrying the next one. Something like the snippet below. I tried axios-retry but I only managed to retry the request if it fails, not make a call before retrying the request. Thanks for any help

```js
axios
  .get('http://myapilink.com/users', {
      headers: {
         'access_token': access_token,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
   })
   .then(function (response) {
    // successfull call
   })
   .err(function (error) {
    // fire an another axios call before retrying the GET request above
    axios
      .post('http://myapilink.com/refresh_token', {
        headers: {
           'refresh_token': refresh_token,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
       .then(function (response) {
        // successfull call - retry the GET request above
       })
       .err(function (error) {
        // handle manual user login because of expired refresh_token
       })
   })
```

Comment: Because each individual axios request is asynchronous you'll either have to make the retry one async or handle this behaviour in the back end (i.e. if the first axios request fails in the backend, do something else before sending a reply)

Comment: Make the retry call async is fine by me but struggling on how to implement it without manually copying the code of the GET call

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a function:

```js
const fn = () => axios
  .get('http://myapilink.com/users', {
      headers: {
         'access_token': access_token,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
   })
   .then(function (response) {
    // successfull call
   })
   .err(function (error) {
    // fire an another axios call before retrying the GET request above
    axios
      .post('http://myapilink.com/refresh_token', {
        headers: {
           'refresh_token': refresh_token,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
       .then(function (response) {
        // successfull call - retry the GET request above
        fn()
       })
       .err(function (error) {
        // handle manual user login because of expired refresh_token
       })
   })

// execute it to start fetching
fn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially if you're wanting to chain asynchronous HTTP requests, it'd be best to handle each step (assuming you don't have like 50 steps). For react, in pseudocode it'd be like:

```
Set state (loading first option -> true)
Axios -> send off first request
If first request in successful, set state (request success -> true)
else set state (loading second option -> true )
if second request is successful, set state (request success -> true)
else set state (http request overall -> failed)
```

Then in your render function display an appropriate message according to the state (i.e. if it's trying to the first one say "loading", if it's loading the second backup one say "loading secondary resource", if BOTH requests fail say "request failed" and do whatever error handling you want, if one of them succeeds then do whatever you need to with the results)

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do but not in pseudocode :)